# how to load DOM on ajax tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to load the `DOM` in my page while using ajax tab.

I am using a `jquery ajax tab plugin` to implement tab functionality.I am having 6 tabs in my application and all tabs are loading data using ajax tab plugin except first one.Since the page is loaded using ajax tab plugin,`DOM` is not loaded.I checked by putting a alert in my page inside the script tag.I am not getting the alert popup also.In the 6 tab,the very first tab is loading the data using normal page load.So,when i am focused on that 1st tab and reload the page,i am getting the alert popup and the script function is working fine.If i click any other tab and reload the page,i am not getting the alert popup and i need to show a alert popup on clicking the `ajax tab`.

What i thought was the `DOM` is not loaded using `ajax tab` data load.So how to load `DOM` while using ajax load.

For example:

sonepage.php

```
<script>
alert("check");
</script>
```

The above will alert the popup when i am focused on first tab and if i am in other than first if i reload the page i am not getting the alert popup.I need to load the DOM in ajax load also.

Is it possible to do this.

Comment: what is the actual issue coming?

Comment: Script will not necessarily run on Ajax loaded content. We need to see the rest of your code *please* :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I need to show the google ads script in that ajax tab page.I am not getting any error in console.It just not loading the ads .

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I need to show the google ads in page which loads using ajax.Please help me with other solution.

Comment: Normal practice is to use partial pages and not have any code on the child pages. It *is* however possible, if you are in control of the Ajax loading, but I gather that is being handled by the tabs? Can you show all the relevant code?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie you want to see ajax tab script code or my html code.It is a file with large number of line how to share.

Comment: I don't think you know what DOM means